# Inequality. $\frac{a}{(b+c)^4}+\frac{b}{(c+a)^4}+\frac{c}{(a+b)^4} \geq \frac{3}{2(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}$

Tags: inequality

> For $a,b,c >0$ prove that :
>
> $$\frac{a}{(b+c)^4}+\frac{b}{(c+a)^4}+\frac{c}{(a+b)^4} \geq \frac{3}{2(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}.$$

I don't know how should I start. It is difficult for me because the denominators has the power equals with 4, I think it must decrease the rank of the power.

danke :)

Comment: Before you even get started, you might notice that both sides are homogeneous of degree $-3$ in the tuple $(a,b,c)$, by which I mean that if you replace $(a,b,c)$ by $(ta,tb,tc)$ then both sides are multiplied by $t^{-3}$. This already improves the chance that the inequality may be true. Also, you get equality for $a=b=c$, so the inequality is sharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality can be written
$$
X := \sum_{cyc} \frac {a(a + b)(a + c)}{(b + c)^3} \geq \frac 3 2
$$
Let's suppose $a \leq b \leq c$. We have
$$
\frac 1 {b + c} \leq \frac 1 {a + c} \leq \frac 1 {a + b} \\
\frac {a(a + b)(a + c)} {(b + c)^2} \leq 
\frac {b(b + c)(b + a)} {(c + a)^2} \leq
\frac {c(c + a)(c + b)} {(a + b)^2}
$$
Applying Rearrangement Inequality we get
$$
X \geq \sum_{cyc} \frac {a(a + b)}{(b + c)^2}=:Y
$$
Reapplyng Rearrangement Inequality and Nesbitt's Inequality we arrive to
$$
Y \geq \sum_{cyc} \frac a {b + c} \geq \frac 3 2
$$

Comment: There is a problem in the second usage of rearrangement inequality. I mean if I am right you would like to say that $a(a+b)\leq b(b+c)\leq c(c+a)$ right? But how can you assume the inequality between the last two terms? I mean $b\leq c$ but $b+c\geq c+a$

Comment: @Iuli http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt's_inequality

Comment: @uforoboa The Rearrangement Inequality is applied to $\displaystyle \frac a {(b + c)^2} \leq \frac b {(c + a)^2} \leq \frac c {(a + b)^2}$ and $a + b \leq a + c \leq b + c$.

Comment: @Iuli For Nesbitt's Inequality you can also look at example 2.1.2 of "your book": http://aam.org.in/site/sites/default/files/Basics%20of%20Olympiad%20Inequalities_1.pdf.

Comment: I applied RE to  $\displaystyle \frac 1 {b + c} \leq \frac 1 {a + c} \leq \frac 1 {a + b}$ and $\displaystyle \frac {a(a + b)(a + c)} {(b + c)^2} \leq \frac {b(b + c)(b + a)} {(c + a)^2} \leq \frac {c(c + a)(c + b)} {(a + b)^2}$ obtaining $\displaystyle \frac 1 {b + c} \cdot \frac {a(a + b)(a + c)} {(b + c)^2} + \frac 1 {a + c} \cdot  \frac {b(b + c)(b + a)} {(c + a)^2} + \frac 1 {a + b} \cdot \frac {c(c + a)(c + b)} {(a + b)^2} \geq \frac 1 {a + c} \cdot \frac {a(a + b)(a + c)} {(b + c)^2} + \frac 1 {a + b} \cdot  \frac {b(b+c)(b+a)}{(c+a)^2} + \frac 1 {b+c}\cdot\frac {c(c+a)(c+b)}{(a+b)^2}$

Comment: @AlbertH... Ok this is exactly what I was pointing at. In this last form it is fine to me.

Comment: ok . Now we have to prove that: 
$$\frac{a(a+b)}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{b(b+c)}{(a+c)^2}+\frac{c(c+a)}{(a+b)^2} \geq \frac{3}{2}.$$ 

Now how do you apply Rearrangements Inequality knowing that: 

$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b} \geq \frac{3}{2} ? $$ merci:)

Comment: @AlbertH Yes, yes. I catch the idea how to apply . Thanks :)